# How to parse and redefine variable in batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need to ping multiple ip addresses in my vlan.
How can I parse the 2-4 digit variable into xx.xx?

```
If it is 4 digits(1111), it needs to be redefined as 11.11
If it is 3 digits(222), it needs to be 02.22
If it is 2 digits(77), it needs to be 00.77
```

How do I do that?

I have tried counting strings, but I have failed misreably at iy.

```
SET /P _inputname= Enter Your Input Number(2-4 Digits):
START cmd /k ping 10.%_inputname%.55 /t
START cmd /k ping 10.%_inputname%.66 /t
START cmd /k ping 10.%_inputname%.77 /t
```

Comment: Consider a more capable platform, like Powershell.

Comment: `set "_inputname=00%_inputname:~-4,2%.%_inputname:~-2%"`, then `set "_inputname=%_inputname:~-4%"`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prepend the number with zeroes,
and get from 4th last position 2 places print a dot and the last 2 places.

```
:: Q:\Test\2019\05\24\SO_56298026.cmd
@Echo off
for %%A in (1111,222,77) do call :sub %%A
SET /P _inputname= Enter Your Input Number(2-4 Digits):
Call :sub %_inputname%
goto :Eof

:sub
set var=0000%1
Echo %Var:~-4,2%.%Var:~-2%
```

Sample output:

```
> Q:\Test\2019\05\24\SO_56298026.cmd
11.11
02.22
00.77
Enter Your Input Number(2-4 Digits):33
00.33
```

Comment: Is there a way to remove the leading zero?  For example 00 = 0 and 05=5?

Comment: That contradicts your initial requirements, instead of the last echo echo you could set the var `set "Var=%Var:~-4,2%.%Var:~-2%"` and check if the 1st char is a zero `if "%var:~0,1"=="0" set "var=%var:~1%`

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to test string length, this however will also no allow more than 4 characters to be entered.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion & set 4max=
:begin
set /p "str=Enter 2-4 digits: "
set "4max=%str:~4,1%
if defined 4max cls & echo you entered to many characters & goto begin
for /l %%i in (0,1,10) do if not "%str%"=="!str:~0,%%i!" (
    set /a ln+=1
 ) else goto :done
:done
if %ln% equ 4 set str=%str:~0,2%.%str:~2,2%
if %ln% equ 3 set str=0%str:~0,1%.%str:~1,2%
if %ln% equ 2 set str=00.%str%
echo(%str%
```

Comment: Is there a way to remove the leading zero?  For example 00 = 0 and 05=5?

Comment: Yes there are ways